# Phaser + TypeScript strict mode

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, strict

I'm starting my adventure with Phaser.io and I wanted to create project in TypeScript that takes full advantage of it's compiler. By that I mean running TS in the `strict` mode. One of the advantages (for me) is the additional safety from nullable object. And this is where it doesn't go well with Phaser.

All of the examples I have seen till now suggest writing in the following pattern:

```
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  player: null;

  create() {
    this.player = this.physics.add.image(...)
  }

  update() {
    //...

    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocity(-100)
    }
  }
}
```

So, creating a nullable `player` member and then assigning it's value is recommended. This is where TypeScript's strict mode shows error: `Object is possibly 'null'.`

The best idea I had to deal with this situation is using monads like `Maybe`. But that seems for me at this point like an overkill. So I wonder, if there are other patterns or ways of using Phaser, that would allow me to have the strict mode on without going as far as using monads.

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak I've updated the post with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option will be just map type like

```
class X {
  player: Player | null = null;

  create() {
    this.player = new Player();
  }

  do() {
    (this.player as Player) / 2;
  }
}
```

Or use `!` to skip initial property check

```js
class X {
  player!: number;

  create() {
    this.player = 42;
  }

  do() {
    this.player / 2;
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20player%3A%20number%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20create()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.player%20%3D%2042%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20do()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(this.player%20as%20number)%20%2F%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20X1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20player!%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20create()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.player%20%3D%2042%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20do()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.player%20%2F%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)